# Is there a good way to dynamically create non-linear equations for scipy.optimize.root or scipy.optimize.fsolve?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy, sympy

I need to solve a large system of non-linear equations (static truss system).
The equations are derived from nodes (xyz) and their constraints (position, forces).

For now we are using Mathematica for this task, but we would like to migrate to Python. 
But with Mathematica (or EES (engineering equation solver) or SymPy) it is pretty convenient. I throw a bunch of stuff in like node positions or forces on nodes and it does some magic and creates the equations by itself combining the input and solve them.

If I want to use `scipy.optimize.root` I have to somehow get the equations.

`scipy.optimize.root` and `scipy.optimize.fsolve` need the equations in the following format:

```
def func(x):
    out = [x[0]*cos(x[1]) - 4], 
           x[1]*x[0] - x[1] - 5)
    return out
```

But in my case there will be up to 5000 equations that define the system.

One thing that came to my mind would be to use `eval()` and fiddle the equations to a string somehow.

In the end I would like to have an object-oriented approach where a node or a constraint knows how to transform itself to an equation.
A very simple skeleton could be

```
n = Node(5, 2, 6)
n.to_equation()

f = ForceConstraint(1, 2, 3)
f.to_equation()
```

and this would somehow transform to equations like

```
x[0] - 5, 
x[1] - 2,
x[2] - 6,
x[2] ** 2 - x[1] * x[0] # and some non-linear stuff
```

to describe the overall system.

Basically there should be some magic part that looks at the matching parts of the equations and constraints.
E.g. look through all info you have on Node1's `x` direction and merge that into equations, or search for all info you have on the forces in `y` direction on Node2.

Is `scipy` the correct tool for the job at all? 
Does someone have a good idea how to do this?

Comment: How similar are the equations? Do they have a common structure?

Comment: No, they are not similar, can be depend on just one or two variables or several hundred if the nodes depend on each other.

Comment: I do not see how the `x[2] ** 2 - x[1] * x[0]` can be derived from `Node(5, 2, 6)`. What are the rules? I think you need to explain in more detail how the `to_equation()` part has to look like i.e. explain better the translation from input to output.

Comment: I added some info to the question. The equation was more of an example.

Comment: You can define f as f(x, a, b, c,...), and pass the a, b, c as arguments using the `args=(a,b,c...)` keyword in `scipy.optimize.root`. The arguments can be anything (booleans, arrays, numbers). Maybe you can play with that to contemplate the set of different equations or parameters?

Comment: Will take a look at that. Does someone have an idea about how Mathematica's magic is working internally?

Comment: You need a somewhat more realistic example, even if it’s written in Mathematica.  More precise terminology will also help: for starters, you don’t write *equations* for `scipy`: you write (mathematical) *functions*, even if they’re implicitly supposed to be 0 (instead of, say, being minimized).  And is `x` your entire state vector with thousands of elements?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be interested in [`symfit`](https://github.com/tBuLi/symfit). It's a package I wrote to connect `scipy` with `sympy`.

I'm not exactly sure what your specific equations are, but any expression you can write in `sympy` can in principle be fed to `symfit`. For example, for your simple example above you could write:

```
from symfit import parameters, variables, Fit
import numpy as np

x0, x1, x2 = parameters('x0, x1, x2')
y0, y1, y2, y3 = variables('y0, y1, y2, y3')

model_dict = {
    y0: x0 - 5,
    y1: x1 - 2,
    y2: x2 - 6,
    y3: x2 ** 2 - x1 * x0
}

fit = Fit(model_dict, y0=np.array(0.0), y1=np.array(0.0), y2=np.array(0.0), y3=np.array(0.0))
fit_result = fit.execute()
print(fit_result)
```

`Variable` and `Parameter` objects in symfit are just sympy `Symbol` subclasses, so you can do all the sympy manipulations on these expressions that you want. For example, you could have defined your Node as

```
>>> x, x_0 = symbols('x, x_0')
>>> Node = x - x_0
```

And then make the lines of your model by repeatedly applying e.g.

```
>>> Node.subs({x: x1, x_0: 2})
x1 - 2
```

Lastly you add your constraint and presto: fittable model! Check the [docs](http://symfit.readthedocs.org/) for more info or ask me  any follow up question.